# Find Items in a Log that have never been tagged with keyword

Tags: filter

I have a log file that creates an entry everytime an item has something done to it...(`1, M1, M2, V1, V2, etc`). So each item can be listed several times in this log file with one of the keywords attached to that entry.

```
Item1 .. M1
----------
Item1 .. V2
----------
Item2 .. V1
----------
Item3 .. M1
----------
Item3 .. 1
----------
Item4 .. V2
----------
Item4 .. 1
----------
Item4 .. M2
----------
```

I'm trying to build a query that searches this log file and finds ONLY the items that have never been tagged with a `1` or `M1` or `M2`. I'm really only looking for items that have been tagged with the V1 or V2. If the item was a tagged with anything else I don't want it in my results.

I hope that makes sense.

I'm using a form of `DB2 SQL`